# How to zero out unallocated memory ram?

Tags: linux, ram

How do you set the kernel to zero out pages of unallocated memory ? Does it slow down the system ?

Kernel : 4.6.4-1-ARCH

Comment: Missing details: which kernel, why "unallocated memory"?

Comment: What is it you're wanting to do?  Go through every unallocated page of physical memory _and_ swap and zero it out?  That could be slow (imaging 256Gb RAM, 256Gb swap).  Or just ensure memory newly allocated to programs is zero'd?  (kernel already does this).  Or something else?

Comment: @StephenHarris  I' d like to temporarily store passwords in variables in bash scripts. I would like to wipe out unused memory at least once after startup.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to how the kernel handles the memory? A good source is http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html

Answer (score 0):

In essence, your question is: ["Are passwords stored in memory safe?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/are-passwords-stored-in-memory-safe). Resuming the answer: **you have to rely on the operating system and/or trust in root and/or hardware.**

Anyway, in Linux, you can do some things:

- Use SELinux/Grsecurity
- Prevent the use of `ptrace()`
- Relay in physical hardware if possible

#### Some resources:

- [Are passwords stored in memory safe?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/are-passwords-stored-in-memory-safe)
- [Keeping secrets from root
  on Linux](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7801/keeping-secrets-from-root-on-linux)
- [Can the root user be removed from a Unix-system to    prevent
  privilege escalation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/107887/can-the-root-user-be-removed-from-a-nix-system-to-prevent-privilege-escalation)